# Ubuntu17.04 Hard disk repeatedly gets corrupted

Tags: boot, nvidia, 17.04, nouveau, 17.10

I have tried Ubuntu 17.04 and 17.10 (2nd Sep 2017) multiple times
Dual booting with Windows 7, but i switch manually using the bios
After a couple of reboots the had drive ext4 partitions get corrupted and i have to fsck to get it to atleast boot  from the intramfs screen
(fsck of my 250GB /home/ partition is still running since 3+ hrs)

I have nvdia gtx 960 and was still in the open-source nouveau driver

This was the message i got from intramfs
[image: log when going to intramfs]

Any idea whats wrong, or how i can get my Ubuntu stable

EDIT:

S.M.A.R.T attributes from GSmartControl

```
SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x002f   100   100   ---    Pre-fail  Always       -       1087
  2 Throughput_Performance  0x0026   252   252   ---    Old_age   Always       -       0
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0023   086   082   ---    Pre-fail  Always       -       4464
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   099   099   ---    Old_age   Always       -       2016
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   252   252   ---    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x002e   252   252   ---    Old_age   Always       -       0
  8 Seek_Time_Performance   0x0024   252   252   ---    Old_age   Offline      -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   100   100   ---    Old_age   Always       -       10463
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0032   252   252   ---    Old_age   Always       -       0
 11 Calibration_Retry_Count 0x0032   100   100   ---    Old_age   Always       -       68
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   099   099   ---    Old_age   Always       -       1755
183 Runtime_Bad_Block       0x0032   252   252   ---    Old_age   Always       -       0
184 End-to-End_Error        0x0033   252   252   ---    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
191 G-Sense_Error_Rate      0x0022   100   100   ---    Old_age   Always       -       50
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0022   252   252   ---    Old_age   Always       -       0
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0032   088   088   ---    Old_age   Always       -       124385
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0002   061   051   ---    Old_age   Always       -       39 (Min/Max 21/51)
195 Hardware_ECC_Recovered  0x003a   100   100   ---    Old_age   Always       -       0
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   252   252   ---    Old_age   Always       -       0
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0032   100   100   ---    Old_age   Always       -       3
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0030   252   252   ---    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x0036   200   200   ---    Old_age   Always       -       0
200 Multi_Zone_Error_Rate   0x002a   100   100   ---    Old_age   Always       -       57
223 Load_Retry_Count        0x0032   100   100   ---    Old_age   Always       -       68
225 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0032   088   088   ---    Old_age   Always       -       124385
241 Total_LBAs_Written      0x0032   097   097   ---    Old_age   Always       -       4628271
242 Total_LBAs_Read         0x0032   100   094   ---    Old_age   Always       -       521227
254 Free_Fall_Sensor        0x0032   252   252   ---    Old_age   Always       -       0
```

The fsck i had run from busybox succeed an i am able to login now

EDIT 2: I had Ext2Fsd version 0.69.1035-09.14 installed on my windows 7

Comment: MOre likely than not your hard drive is about to fail completely. There is no way to fix hard drive errors, fsck simply reallocates bad blocks. BACKUP YOUR DATA IMMEDIATELY. THEN RUN Smartmon - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Smartmontools

Comment: If you mean the S.M.A.R.T attributes I have checked using Sea tools for windows (http://www.seagate.com/in/en/support/downloads/seatools/) and the test passed

Comment: I am not familiar with that tool. I am very concerned that either your hard drive is failing or you are doing something bad like powering off your computer by pulling the power plug. Run the fsck command from a live image and post the results. It would also help if you ran the smartmontools and posted those results.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen updated with SMART attributes

Comment: Does "i switch manually using the bios" mean you don't do controlled shutdowns on either system? That will lead to eventual disk corruption. Shutdown Ubuntu via the `shutdown` command.

Comment: @waltinator I use the shutdown/reboot buttons on the GUI on both, I just hit F12 on bios and select the hard disk to boot from when starting

Comment: In Windows, did you install a driver that allows Windows to read/write to EXT4 partitions? If so, that's your problem.

Comment: @heynnema I cant read the ext4 partitions from windows, it shows shows up in tools like device manager and that's it. But i do have https://sourceforge.net/projects/ext2fsd/ ill remove this and check

Comment: @tejas ext2fsd would qualify :-)

Comment: Your hard drive is failing. Back your data up IMMEDIATELY in the order of most important to least important and get a new hard drive.

Comment: @heynnema I uninstalled ext2fsd (Ext2Fsd-0.69.1035-09.14 )and that solved the issue.  Do you want to make it an answer out of it?

Comment: @KryštofPíštěk What makes you say that? (The hard drive is definitely not new and contains no data at all. thats wht i am trying out Ubuntu on it :)

Comment: @tejas answer made. Thanks! Glad your problem is solved.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen Please see my answer that solved tejas problem.

Comment: @heynnema - Good pick up, those details should be added to question.

Comment: @tejas The S.M.A.R.T. data. If you have no data, you don't need a backup.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the comments...

Windows third-party drivers that allow the user to read/write to Ubuntu Ext2/3/4 partitions seem to corrupt the Ubuntu file system.

You have ext2fsd (Ext2Fsd-0.69.1035-09.14 ) installed. You should uninstall it, and your file system corruption problem should be solved.

Then check the file system on your Ubuntu partition...

- boot to the GRUB menu
- choose Advanced Options
- choose Recovery mode
- choose Root access
- at the # prompt, type `sudo fsck -f /`
- repeat the `fsck` command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

If for some reason you can't do the above...

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB
- start `gparted` and determine which /dev/sdaX is your Ubuntu EXT4 partition
- quit `gparted`
- open a `terminal` window
- type `sudo fsck -f /dev/sdaX` # replacing X with the number you found earlier
- repeat the fsck command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

Comment: Microsoft even agrees: Microsoft says don't do it: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/commandline/2016/11/17/do-not-change-linux-files-using-windows-apps-and-tools/