# Terminal command to gracefully shutdown Ubuntu

Tags: command-line, 16.04, shutdown

I am looking for a terminal command to gracefully shutdown Ubuntu. Right now I am using

```
sudo shutdown -h now
```

It seems however that this is the cause for some file system corruptions which can only be fixed manually. Attached is one example, however, others on different systems and partitions have been observed and I am not feeling well with fixing them with fsck -fy /dev/sdxx everytime they appear.

Best

[image: Filesystem corruption]

[image: FSCK result]

Comment: shutdown command doesn't require root access , so "sudo" is unnecessary . Actually the proper way for shutting down the system is to let systemd do it itself . You can achieve this via " init 0 " ( and init 6 for restart ) or " telinit 0 " or "systemctl isolate runlevel0 " . All of them should work. I don't think it's a problem with the "shutdown" command.

Comment: I would check for other issues that cause your logical disk corruption, as I've never noticed any issues on any system using `shutdown` (which will shudown the OS safely; the -h needed to also turn off hardware as command relates to OS).  Yes I would see where (`whereis`) your `shutdown` is, if it's official code (ie. Ubuntu code, and not something else, as it should be calling init/systemd to do the work) or someone has scripted something else which is your issue....

Comment: @ParsaMousavi Runlevels are a legacy concept and only have some compatibility wrappers in systemd. `init 0` just calls `telinit 0` instead, which is a link to systemctl, which in turn is internally mapped to just `systemctl isolate poweroff.target` - the same as the plain `shutdown now` command. Don't think or teach in runlevels when you use systemd, think in targets. Further reading: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/196014/103151

Comment: Seems like you have discovered a bug with that "*same software setup*" handling of [SIGTERM](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Termination-Signals.html). Do a bit more troubleshooting; try to narrow the scope of the problem to a single application (reproducible in minimum steps), then file a bug report detailing those minimum steps to reliably reproduce. In a test environment of stock 16.04, I was unable to reproduce the problem -- shutdown was clean.

Answer (score 0):

Shutdown command does the shutdown gracefully. How did you come to the conclusion that shutting down is causing the problem?

Checkout [hard disk repeatedly gets corrupted](https://askubuntu.com/questions/954515/ubuntu17-04-hard-disk-repeatedly-gets-corrupted)

1. You can add the `fsck` to your `GRUB` so that you won't have to do this manually every time.
2. Backup all your data because this could mean your hard disk is damaged.

Comment: This is happening on various new computers with the same software setup. Updates are deactivated and only one program is run, which only reads and writes in the home directory. The only thing that is interacting with the OS obviously is shutting down the computer which is done from within the program via the mentioned command.

Answer (score 0):

> with the same software setup

That must be the common denominator. I've used shutdown -h now on many systems for >20 years and never had an issue with it. Even on heavily utilised database servers.

What software are you using? I'd suggest that one of your applications is taking too long to shut down or something similar.